# How to stop processors spinning while waiting?

Tags: c++, mpi

I'm using MPI (required by a library) to do some work. I'd like the worker processors to pause for a while while the master thread does some non-trivial work. At the moment I have the worker threads pausing waiting for an `MPI_Bcast` but they're spinning (100% CPU usage) wasting resources that could be used elsewhere. Is there a way to pause a process and have it rest?

Comment: I'm not familiar with MPI but I'm surprised it would do a busy loop. Do you have the relevant part of the worker process that you could share with us?

Comment: I would think that there should be some form of wait for the MPI_Bcast that each thread could use.

Comment: MPI implementations often busy-wait because users wants minimal latency. You should try MPI_Ibcast and poll at the frequency you like while doing work on that thread otherwise.